# PostgreSQL check if all surrogate IDs exist in table

Tags: arrays, postgresql

How do I check if an arbitrary array of user IDs, e.g., `'{1, 2, 3}'`, all exist in my `users` table, where `users.id` is a `bigserial` and `PRIMARY KEY`?

UPDATE: Thank you for the different solutions. Which method is the most efficient if the `users` table has TONS of rows and the array of user IDs is relatively small?

Comment: I didnt think will have to write this for someone with 40k but your question look very sloopy. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: As per your update: use EXPLAIN ANALYZE and compare execution plans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = array_length(array[1,2,3], 1)
             THEN 'You Have all'
             ELSE 'SomeOne is missing'
        END as result
FROM    users
WHERE   users.id  = ANY(ARRAY[1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you! Is this the fastest query for a big table and a small array?

Comment: @mattdipasquale: check the execution plan

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name OK. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to aggregate your ids and use contains operator for arrays

```
select array_agg(id) @> '{1,2,3}' from users
```

Another one would be to unnest the values from array and join it with the table to perform a *boolean and* across the set

```
select bool_and(u.id is not null)
from unnest('{1,2,3}'::int[]) as t(id)
left join users u using ( id )
```

There are many other methods to deal with it, so this will be merely your choice.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder which method is fastest for a big table and a small array.

Comment: Putting `unnest()` into the select list is discouraged. But you don't need the derived table anyway, you can join directly: `select bool_and(u.id is not null) from unnest(array[1,2,3]) as t(id) left join users u using (id)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're right about the superfluous derived table, I wasn't sure so didn't want to risk not working. Could you tell me why is it discouraged actually?

Answer (score 0):

This query works for me:

```
WITH expected_users AS (SELECT unnest(users) AS id FROM array[1,2,3] AS users)
SELECT NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
        1
    FROM 
        expected_users eu
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users u WHERE eu.id = u.id)
)
```